# PHP and css link button

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

instead of boring button i decided to style a link button for my login page. Only thing is I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Here's the code before the link button:

```
 <div id="centerDoc">
    <div id="loginScreen">
     <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>User Login </strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Username</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><?php   require_once 'checkLogin.php';   ?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>

    </form>
```

So the only difference is instead of:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
```

I've added:

```
<td><a href="#" class="loginButton" name="login" value="login">Log in</a></td>
```

But as i suspected it doesn't do anything. How can i fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: I'd like to use a custom css button instead of the default button. My understanding was that this needs to be done with a link button. But I also need to get the post event so that `checkLogin.php` can do the necessary processing by doing the isset test `if (isset($_POST['login'])){`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Mischa: i believe this question is related to PHP since the button click needs to send a post event to checkLogin.php

Comment: It's still not really about PHP, but after your edit there's at least some PHP code. Feel free to edit the tag back in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style an input to look nice, but for a link, you will need to include the following attribute:

```
onclick="document.forms[0].submit(); return false;"
```

You also might not need the `name` or `value` attributes depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried the following: `<td><a href="#" class="loginButton" onClick="return document.forms[0].submit()">Log in</a></td>`
Which doesn't work. Am I missing something else?

Comment: did you try replacing the `forms[0]` with `forms['form1']`? If that doesn't work, is there an example of the script site?

Comment: yeah not having any luck with that either. Note that I also have `<tr><td colspan="3"><?php   require_once 'checkLogin.php';   ?></td></tr>` so its all processed on the same page. in checkLogin.php i'm checking `if (isset($_POST['login'])){` Which now suggests its not gonna work. I'm just not sure what modifications I need to make here..

Comment: You have to add a hidden field to your form: `<input type="hidden" name="login" value="1">`. Then the solution above should work.

Comment: @greenpool as Mischa said, you would need to add that hidden input to make it work with your system

Comment: @Mischa and @cgoddard : i tried `<input type="hidden" name="login" value="1">
<td><a href="#" class="loginButton" onClick="return document.forms[0].submit()">Log in</a></td>` which works! thanks guys. Just one last question. not very familar with code `return document.forms[0].submit()` - can you give me some insight into what this is doing or a link to some content i can read up on?

Comment: @greenpool actually, I think I erred on that one, it should have a separate command after `submit()` that is `return false;`. The return is a `true` or `false` as to whether default browser behaviour (in this case, follow `href`) will take place as well.

Answer (score 1):

quick google search on "javascript form submit"

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Edit: cgoddard's solution is nicer

Answer (score 0):

you also need to do have definition for the loginButton as

```
.loginButton {
    display:block;
    width:90px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

and this needs to be loaded in the page as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.loginButton {
    display:block;
    width:90px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" class="loginButton" name="login" value="login">Log in</a>
</body>
```

The above sample should work for you.

Comment: So, have your got your answer or you are still having trouble.